# how to make method for download file?

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

i tried to make method for downloading file the name of my file is in the database

i did that in my controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/librairie/downloadResume/{resume}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String downloadResume(@PathVariable ("resume") String resume, HttpServletRequest request) 
{

    Livre livre = dc.selectLivres().stream().filter(e -> e.getResume().equals(resume)).findFirst().get();

     gestPanier = new GestPanier(request);

    return "../resources/resume/${resume}"; 
}
```

and in my view

```
<tr>
            <td>${livre.isbn}</td>
            <td>${livre.auteur}</td>
            <td>${livre.titre}</td>
            <td>${livre.prix}</td>
            <td>${livre.quantite}</td>
             <td><img src="../resources/img/${livre.photo}"  /></td>
             <td><button onclick="location.href='/examenIntra/librairie/downloadResume/${livre.resume}'">Voir résumé </button></td>
            <td>

              <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='/examenIntra/librairie/acheterLivre/${livre.isbn}'">Acheter</button> 
                            </td>
            </tr>
```

and my database

```
      CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Livres](
         [Isbn] [nvarchar](13) NOT NULL,
         [Auteur] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
         [Titre] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Prix] [money] NOT NULL,
[Quantite] [int] NOT NULL,
[Photo] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Resume] [nvarchar](255)NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Livres] PRIMARY KEY ([Isbn] )
 ) 
 GO
```

but its dosn't work

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be in your button's onclick = location.href.

In you onclick, you are simply passing a string. You are expecting "${livre.resume}" this will be dynamically formed, but it won't. Please generate this button properly.

Comment: what should i do with this button?